# could not run generate statements after installing rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I tried installing the paperclip plugin from my rails project root directory, by

```
rails plugin install http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git
```

vendor/plugins/paperclip was created successfully. But after that i could not run any generate (`rails generate scaffold` ) commands . I'm getting error as

```
D:\rr\pr2>rails g scaffold car name:string
D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/d
ependencies.rb:240:in `require': no such file to load -- cocaine (LoadError)
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
        from D:/rr/pr2/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:45:in `<top (re
quired)>'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
        from D:/rr/pr2/vendor/plugins/paperclip/init.rb:1:in `block in <class:Pl
ugin>'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/pl
ugin.rb:80:in `eval'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/pl
ugin.rb:80:in `block in <class:Plugin>'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:25:in `run'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:49:in `each'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/ap
plication.rb:92:in `initialize!'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/ra
iltie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from D:/rr/pr2/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/ap
plication.rb:78:in `require'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/ap
plication.rb:78:in `require_environment!'
        from D:/sprtcr/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What's your Rails version? Are you using RVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By installing this gem as a plugin, you're not going to get the dependencies that the gem requires. The `paperclip` gem depends on another gem called `cocaine`.

I would really recommend installing the `paperclip` gem by putting it into your `Gemfile` and running `bundle install`.

This is why you should use gems rather than plugins.

Comment: how these kind of details, a naive developer can come across :-(. Thanks for the info. Please make your book with these kind of datas.